# How Do I Access The Test Gamemode?

Tags: wreckfest

I recently purchased The Next Car Game and messed around with a few races and demolition derby's, then I remembered that there is a test game mode that is supposed to come with the full game that has more than the demo.  I searched the game but couldn't find it.  How do I use the test game mode?

Comment: by test game mode do you mean that open area with all the grinders, cannons, toys, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Technology Sneak Peak 2.0" should be added as a separate entry in your Steam library (assuming you purchased it via Steam). The library entry should be called "Next Car Game Sneak Peek 2.0" (App ID: 36742).

If you purchased it via Bug Bear's website, you should have a link to download the Sneak Peak in whatever confirmation emails/on site user profiles were generated during the purchase.

Failing that, it looks like you can get the Sneak Peak by [signing up to their newsletter](http://nextcargame.com/free-technology-demo/).

Comment: I searched the email from Bugbear and found the link.  Thanks for the help!